# Dynamic variables

Tags: java, arrays, variables

I'm tring to assign variables dynamically, but I don't have a clue how to do that.

What my program should do:

> "Write a program to have the user enter three lengths of sides and determine whether the figure is a triangle or not."

This is what I have so far:

```
package triangle;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Triangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the side lengths of a     triangle with each side \nseparated with a ',' and without spaces. (eg. 1,2,3)");
        x += ",";
        int y = -1, a = 0; 
        double z;
        for(int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
        {
            if(x.charAt(i) == ',')
            {
                z = Double.parseDouble(x.substring((y + 1), i));
                y = i;
                a += z;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I would love to do would be to have this in the if statement:

```
int a++;
z(a) = Double.parseDouble(x.substring((y + 1), i));
```

But as I have found out this will not work and I need some kind of array. Sadly, my online class has not started arrays yet and I haven't gotten a grasp of them yet in my own learning.

I would like to make 3 variables (z1, z2, z3) and assign an integer to each one within the if statement.

Edit:
Here's some revised code that now works how I wanted now. Hope this helps someone else in the future!

```
package triangle;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Triangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the side lengths of a     triangle with each side \nseparated with a ',' and without spaces. (eg. 1,2,3)");
        x += ",";
        int y = -1, a = 0; 
        Double[] z = new Double[3];
        for(int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
        {
            if(x.charAt(i) == ',')
            {
                z[a] = Double.parseDouble(x.substring((y + 1), i));
                y = i;
                a++;
            }
        }
        //Some test code to see if it was working
        System.out.println(z[0]);
        System.out.println(z[1]);
        System.out.println(z[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, but... what are you supposed to do? What do you want this code to do?

Comment: It's a school assignment. I Just like going a little beyond whats asked. "Write a program to have the user enter three lengths of sides and determine whether the figure is a triangle or not."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use arrays, especially that you haven't been introduced to them. You can simply use a `Scanner` class, and do something similar to

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // this will read from the standard system input
System.out.println("Please enter three lengths of sides: ");
int a = in.nextInt();
int b = in.nextInt();
int c = in.nextInt();
```

And write some logic (I guess that's the point of your homework) checking if this figure is a triangle.

In case you would like to use arrays , you could declare one by doing:

```
int[] sidesLenghtsArray = new int[3];
```

And then instead of refering to three different `int` variables, you could simply refer to your array elements:

```
int[0] = in.nextInt();
int[1] = in.nextInt();
int[2] = in.nextInt();
```

Just remember - the number in the brackets is the number of elements that your array will have, but refering to that elements, you start counting from 0. That's why we start with `int[0]` (1st element) and end with `int[2]` (3rd element).

Comment: I would use a scanner and three different inputs but I want to use a loop just for some extra challenge and to show my teacher I'm ready for more advanced classes (Like arrays). I'll get back to you once I try implementing the array. Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: @lukeb28 If I may give you a piece of advice - if you want to show your teacher that you are *ready* for more advanced classes, first read some book or tutorial (I'm sure you've got some materials to learn from) on arrays (or whatever you want to learn), instead of asking *before* you actually looked for some info. Hope that will help. If you will have some more questions, do not hesitate to ask!

Comment: I have been watching vswe's summer cources on java.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RtA9xz6W5to&list=PL6lD77ZPqAf3KtS0T8LZ-JTdjogDKas8N
The main reason I needed to ask is because he skipped single dimension arrays and went right to two dimensional arrays, which confused me quite a bit. I just finished implementing the arrays to my code and it is doing exactly as I wanted! Thanks for the help Eel Lee! I think I understand arrays better now that I have applied them in my code.

Comment: Cool, continue to learn :) and if you think my answer helped you, here on StackOverflow you can upvote an answer that you think is good, or even accept it, if you think it solves your problem. Good luck!

Comment: I would give it an up-vote, but that needs at least 15 rep which I don't have. Instead you have my acceptance which I can do. :) 

Keep up the great help!

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support tuple assignment like

```
def (a,b,c) = "1,2,3".split(",")
```

It is possible to do this in Java 8 with a following code:

```
int[] abc = Arrays.stream("1,2,3".split(",")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Here, `a` would be `abc[0]`, `b` is `abc[1]`.

Similar code in Java 7 could be this:

```
String[] abc = "1,2,3".split(",");

int a = Integer.parseInt(a[0]);
int b = Integer.parseInt(a[1]);
int c = Integer.parseInt(a[2]);
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the answer to this question?

Comment: Yes, I'm quite certain. @likeb28 was curious and I gave options. This might be the new API, but it is easy for understanding. Why?

Comment: Thanks for the info but I'm currently running on java 7. I'll keep a note of that for when I do update though!

Answer (score 0):

The very basic idea is that in every triangle when you add the lengths of two sides, the resulting length should be greater than the length of the remaining sides. Let's say a, b, c are the sides of the triangle.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int a=3, b=4, c=5;

    if(a+b > c && a+c>b && c+b>a){
        System.out.println("This is a valid trianlge");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("This is not a valid triangle");
    }
}
```

make sure you replace the values of a,b, and c with the values you gain from user input.

Comment: Thanks for offering help but that was my assignment, not my question. Whats the point of an assignment if someone does it for you? In any case what I came up with is more or less the same as what you offered up. Only difference was that I used an array and did the conditions of where it would not be a triangle.

Comment: You're welcome.I did not offer the full solution as you had to add code to make it work the way the questions asked you. I'm glad you got it to work though.